# error: too few arguments to function 'set_new_node'

Tags: c, function, object

All of the other threads on this error are either in C++ or are a different situation, so I am gonna make a thread for it. I am getting this error although I provide NULL for both of the arguments. Does NULL not work in this situation?

```
typedef struct set {
  struct set_node *head; 
}set_t;

typedef struct setnode{
  const char *key; 
  void *item;
  void *next;
}setnode_t;


set_t *set_new(void)
{
  //Creates NULL node
  set_t *set = count_malloc(sizeof(set_t));

  set->head = set_new_node(NULL, NULL);

  return set; 
}

static *setnode_t set_new_node(const char *key, void *item)
{
  setnode_t *node = count_malloc(sizeof(setnode_t));

  if (node == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                      
    return NULL;
  } else {
    node->key = key;
    node->item = item;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
  }
}
```

Error I got:

```
set.c:53:3: error: too few arguments to function 'set_new_node'
   set->head = set_new_node(NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: If you have a function declaration in some header, show us the declaraiton. your program is not complete. Please always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of functions implementation.

```
static *setnode_t set_new_node(const char *key, void *item)
{
  setnode_t *node = count_malloc(sizeof(setnode_t));

  if (node == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                      
    return NULL;
  } else {
    node->key = key;
    node->item = item;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
  }
}

set_t *set_new(void)
{
  //Creates NULL node
  set_t *set = count_malloc(sizeof(set_t));

  set->head = set_new_node(NULL, NULL);

  return set; 
}
```

In C, the order of functions implementations matter OR put the signature (declaration of `static setnode_t *set_new_node(const char *key, void *item);` before `set_t *set_new(void)` implementation)

Comment: I have the signature in a .h file

Comment: ops.. sorry. I tried your code (only change the '*' of set_new_node return to: static setnode_t * set_new_node()) and I didnot get this error.